# jQuery addClass to a child element not working in Egde

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this structure:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="js-drilldown-back"><a>Back</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

and I'm trying to add a class to the  first  tag, so it becomes this:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="js-drilldown-back"><a class="click-back">Back<a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

The framework I use is adding this back button dynamically, so I can't manually add the class to it. I have tried this code:

```
$(".js-drilldown-back").children("a").addClass("click-back")
```

but it doesn't seem to work in Edge, other browsers seem happy with it. I've also tried:

```
$(".js-drilldown-back:has a").addClass("click-back")
$(".js-drilldown-back:has > a").addClass("click-back")
$(".js-drilldown-back a").addClass("click-back")
$(".js-drilldown-back > a").addClass("click-back")
```

What I'm trying to achieve is when you click the Back button it removes a class from the body tag, ie:

```
$(".click-back").click(function(){
  $("#page").removeClass("submenu-open")
})
```

Targetting the parent (.js-drilldown-back) doesn't seem to work which is why I'm trying to add the class to the child and target this instead.

Comment: You're missing a proper closing tag for that anchor. `</a>`. That might be causing an issue.

Comment: Maybe your code is running before it's been dynamically added by your framework? Try wrapping your code in a setTimeout (to see if it's the issue) and look for a way to hook into your framework completion.

Comment: @Andy that's just my sloppy writing of the question

Comment: @freedomn-m that was the issue, I added a 3.5sec delay around the whole lot and now the class is being added and the removeClass is being triggered when I click the <a> tag. Thanks. Stick this as an answer and I'll mark are correct.

Comment: It's not an ideal solution, more of a patch/hack.  At least it confirms the issue.  There should be a way to hook into your framework telling you it's finished, which would be a better solution (especially in non-Edge where it doesn't take that long)

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to have proper semicolon terminations after each statement.

```js
$(".js-drilldown-back").children("a").addClass("click-back");
```

:first-child seems to work fine in Edge, or maybe the console.log in jsfiddle is being lenient?  I also reworked how you're applying your on click event and confirmed that it removes the class from the anchor.

```js
$(".js-drilldown-back:first-child").addClass("click-back");
console.log( $(".js-drilldown-back:first-child").hasClass("click-back") );

$(document).on("click", ".click-back", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("click-back");
})
```

Console confirms that the anchor has the desired class, i.e., :first-child is working.

[image: Console confirms that the anchor has the desired class]

Upon clicking the anchor, source confirms that the class is removed.  I changed the target just to confirm it was removing something I could see and verify.

[image: Upon clicking the anchor, source confirms that the class is removed]

All tested in Edge here:  https://jsfiddle.net/8bfo9cza/

Comment: `;` are implied by newlines.  Maybe there's an edge-case in Edge (see what I did there?) but unlikely.

Comment: Damn I didn't even know that.  Also, gross.  lol!

Comment: @Lucretius I added in the `;` just in case, but it made no difference